# Mask subdomain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following code within `.htaccess` file of my domain directory to mask my subdomain as `amazon.com` webpage. Its showing `amazon.com` however URL also gets changed `amazon.com`. I did some research online and seems like I am using the correct code. What I am missing?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.amazon.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Use `P` proxy flag instead of `R=301` .

Comment: Do you literally mean "amazon.com" - you aren't just using that as an example URL? There are a "few" technical issues here, but apart from anything, Amazon will most certainly try to block you if you do something like this, or serve you with a cease and desist!?